# How to display remaining post ( in post__in ) if posts are less then post per page?

Tags: sort, pre-get-posts

I am sorting product on product category page. I want to display sale product at first and show remaining product after it. I am using pre_get_posts hook to modify query.

**My CODE**

```
function modify_query( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_product_category() ){
        $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();
       $query->set( 'post__in', $product_ids_on_sale );
       $query->set('orderby', 'post__in' );

    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_query' );
```

But this query is only showing sale products. I want to show ramaning post after the sale products.
For example if my post_per_page is 10, and sale product is 2. Then I want to display 2 sale and 8 remaining products.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest, but not necessarily the most performant, would be using two WP_Query loops, one using `$query->set( 'post__in', $product_ids_on_sale );` and other using `$query->set( 'post__not__in', $product_ids_on_sale );` because these are mutually exclusive. One loop would be used for the main query and other for second loop as [show in this example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#multiple-loops) in the documentation.

You would need to account for the number of items in each loop based on the number of items in the `$product_ids_on_sale` variable AND pagination. And I would the main query for the products NOT in sale.